# Magento 2 Customer Account Information

Tags: magento2

Form Where this content is coming in **Magento2**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This form is built using UI Components. 
You can see its configuration in file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

Comment: thanks for help i want to create image option here can you guide more on that its not save data i add the below code     <field name="image" formElement="file">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
          
        </field>